# Different IP:hostName mappings for same host in `/etc/hosts`. Why does this work?

Tags: ping, hosts, ipv4, host-name-resolution

## My scenario

Relevant entries in my `/etc/hosts` (I have them written in the same order you see them here)

```
172.22.5.107    www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
192.168.1.116   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
```

I use my laptop in my house and school, hence I'm always dealing with 2 address spaces:

- 192.168.1.0/24
- 172.22.0.0/16

So I have those entries because I have a vm with a Wordpress for doing an exercise. That way, it doesn't matter where I am that I'll be able to access my Wordpress (as long as the DHCP offers me the same IP in both networks obviously)

## My question

Knowing all of this, now I can tell you that I just made that configuration in my `/etc/hosts` because one teacher said to me that I only can have 1 record for a name pointing to a single IP. He said to me that If I had a doubled register for the same name, It always take the first one, and stops. But he also said to me that I should try it out, so I did.

The reality, is that for example in my house (where I'm using `192.168.1.0/24`), even though the first record is for the other IP, I still can make a connection, and when I ping the name, the correct IP answers to me. And yes, I did try to be completely sure about this, and I did it in an incognito firefox window, and I also tried to comment the line of the IP of my house to check what happened.

Then, I tried to exchange both records. I mean, I just did this:

```
192.168.1.116   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
172.22.5.107    www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
```

So in this case, obviously it is still working.

And when I went to school, the same happened when using the other address space.

So...
**¿Why is it said that you can only have 1 record for a name in your `/etc/hosts`, if this configuration actually worked for me?**

**¿Is firefox, the `ping` binary, or anything that you use, doing an internal process of name resolution to check what's the entry that actually works, before doing the final connection?**
I'm asking this because for example with `ping`, you just start getting an answer from the IP that works. You don't get failed connections like trying to connect to the other previous IPs

Comment: DId you also flush your DNS cache, if there is any?

Comment: It's not a cache related situation, because I tested this behaviour in 2 completely different PCs (mine, where I was working on this task, and the one of my teacher, which obviously didn't have these records cached and we tested the behaviour with a different name, IPs... Etc) @kmotoko

Comment: As a side note. Your machine has a set of addresses of its own. They are independent of the external network. They are `127.0.0.1` to `127.255.255.254` (`127.*.*.*`). The default one is `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Yep! I knew that, but I don't know what that has to do with my question here @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: It is a side note to help avoid XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a few tests on my debian/wsl

```
~$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-OMM8LBC 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #864-Microsoft Thu Nov 07 15:22:00 PST 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# /etc/hosts
172.22.5.107   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # Unreachable IP from my LAN
216.58.198.164 www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for www.google.com
192.168.0.12   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for another running machine on my LAN
157.240.1.35   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for www.facebook.com

~$ ping www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
PING www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.12): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=49.9 ms
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.12): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=5.85 ms
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.12): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=5.58 ms
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.12): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=6.25 ms
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.12): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=6.19 ms
--- www.wordpress-rend-adri.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 9ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.575/14.754/49.919/17.584 ms
```

So `ping` picked the local IP placed between two working WAN IP.

Second test:

```
/etc/hosts
172.22.5.107   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # Unreachable IP from my LAN
216.58.198.164 www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for www.google.com
#192.168.0.12   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for one running machine on my LAN
157.240.1.35   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for www.facebook.com

~$ ping www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
PING www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (172.22.5.107) 56(84) bytes of data.
# Stuck here
```

Third test:

```
/etc/hosts
#172.22.5.107   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # Unreachable IP from my LAN
216.58.198.164 www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for www.google.com
#192.168.0.12   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for one running machine on my LAN
157.240.1.35   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for www.facebook.com

~$ ping www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
PING www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (216.58.198.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (216.58.198.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=24.5 ms
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (216.58.198.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=22.4 ms
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (216.58.198.164): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=21.7 ms
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (216.58.198.164): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=30.5 ms

--- www.wordpress-rend-adri.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 7ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.734/24.768/30.457/3.440 ms
```

Fourth test:

```
/etc/hosts
#172.22.5.107  www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # Unreachable IP from my LAN
216.58.198.164 www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for www.google.com
192.168.0.12   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for one running machine on my LAN
192.168.0.1    www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for my router
157.240.1.35   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com # IP for www.facebook.com

~$ ping www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
PING www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.56 ms
64 bytes from www.wordpress-rend-adri.com (192.168.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.35 ms

--- www.wordpress-rend-adri.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 2ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.349/1.455/1.561/0.106 ms
```

So my conclusion is that `ping` does not try one IP after another. It favours router, local IP over WAN IP.

**Update :**

The choice of IP above is confirmed by following python command:

```
python -c 'import socket;print(socket.gethostbyname("www.wordpress-rend-adri.com"))'
```

Comment: I was getting really confused but you cleared out my doubts with those tests. So then we can assume that based on priority, the resolver takes the first mapping it encounters? For example, if I have a lot of public ips resolutions and private ones, but without one for the router, it will take the first private ip mapping it encounters. Am I right? Another last thing, is that I know nothing about python, so could you explain me what that command does? @Philippe

Comment: Yes, ping takes the first local IP. The python command gives IP for "www.wordpress-rend-adri.com". What I meant was the IPs ping takes happen to eb exactly the same as gethostbyname gives.

Answer (score 1):

Consider when you have these entries in `/etc/hosts`,

> ```
> 172.22.5.107    www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
> 192.168.1.116   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
> ```

It used to be that looking up `www.wordpress-rend-adri.com` would return (at most) only entries from the first line that matched, i.e. `172.22.5.107` in this instance.

What happens on (some) modern Linux distributions is that the entire `/etc/hosts` file is scanned for matches, and you will get not only `172.22.5.107` but also `192.168.1.116`.

This surprised me.

(In fact, I'd written a complete answer confirming your teacher's perspective, except that when I actually tested it I found that it was no longer true.)

1. Lookup `www.wordpress-rend-adri.com` will return `172.22.5.107` *and* `192.168.1.116`
2. Lookup `172.22.5.107` will return `www.wordpress-rend-adri.com`
3. Lookup `192.168.1.116` will return `www.wordpress-rend-adri.com`

Demonstration, assuming these two records are in the local `/etc/hosts`

```
grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files dns

tail -n2 /etc/hosts
192.168.1.116   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
172.22.5.107    www.wordpress-rend-adri.com

getent hosts www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
192.168.1.116   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
172.22.5.107    www.wordpress-rend-adri.com

getent hosts 172.22.5.107
172.22.5.107    www.wordpress-rend-adri.com

getent hosts 192.168.1.116
192.168.1.116   www.wordpress-rend-adri.com
```

I would surmise that the reason you can use either address in either context is that your web browser, etc., is correctly attempting each possible IP address from the set (i.e. `172.22.5.107` and `192.168.1.116`) until it gets a successful connection.

Comment: your answer helped me to confirm that the system does scan the entire file for matches. My teacher and me thought once that maybe it was the browser who had this decision, but with the other answer things changed, because `ping` also does that function. I'm wondering that maybe is the resolver who is in charge of all this process.  I didn't not chose your answer as the bounty winner just because that person showed a lot of useful and clarifying tests, but thanks for your answer also! @roaima

Comment: @AdriánJaramillo I'm pleased you're happy with your results. The tests I gave in the demonstration section of my answer are at a lower level than just `ping`; everything that looks up host names/addresses using the standard library routines uses `getent` in one way or another.